# Парсинг содержимого элемента по его name

Tags: java, xml, dom, xmlparser

Есть

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<map>
      <string name="photo_link"></string>  
      <string name="user_id">372fb7af6e0d2719d1babb6ad86dab46</string>
</map>
```

Хочу спарсить вторую строку по ее name, name="user_id", а точнее спарсить ее содержимое через XML DOM, как это сделать.

Это не работает:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new File("/Users/k1ceargy/Desktop/testFile.xml"));

    Element element = document.getDocumentElement();
    System.out.println(element.getAttributes().getNamedItem("user_id").getNodeValue());
```

Comment: Используй XPath вот пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445408/how-to-get-specific-xml-elements-with-specific-attribute-value

Comment: не совсем удобный способ, есть кое что другое?

Comment: @k1ceargy, удобнее xpath может быть css-селектор и то не всегда :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одним из вариантов вытаскивания значения будет через xpath выражения.

Пример:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new File("/Users/k1ceargy/Desktop/testFile.xml"));

...

XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();

// Или так: "map/string[@name=\"user_id\"]/text()"
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//*[@name=\"user_id\"]/text()");

// Если элементов несколько нужно найти указывать XPathConstants.NODESET и приводить к NodeList
Node nl = (Node) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);

// Или nl.getTextContent()
System.out.println(nl.getNodeValue());  // 372fb7af6e0d2719d1babb6ad86dab46
```

---

Еще можно через работу с DOM вручную найти нужные элементы:

```
NodeList nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("string");
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodes.item(i);
    Node attr = node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name");
    if (attr != null && "user_id".equals(attr.getTextContent())) {
        System.out.println(node.getTextContent()); // 372fb7af6e0d2719d1babb6ad86dab46
    }
}
```

---

**PS.** Если кода много, то всегда его можно обернуть в функцию:

```
static String getNodeValueByName(Document doc, String name) throws XPathExpressionException {
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String xpathStr = String.format("//*[@name=\"%s\"]/text()", name);
    
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpathStr);
    Node nl = (Node) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
    if (nl == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return nl.getNodeValue();
}

...

System.out.println(getNodeValueByName(document, "photo_link")); // null
System.out.println(getNodeValueByName(document, "user_id"));    // 372fb7af6e0d2719d1babb6ad86dab46
```